# Work-around for not being able to deploy multiple applications to a single EC2 instance using AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, continuous-deployment

We have a web app running using AWS Elastic Beanstalk (via Visual Studio 2010).

We now want a second site on the same server for development and presentation 
purposes. I want to point to the new location for continuous deployment. Once
we are happy, I want to switch back to the original (production) destination.

I have been doing some reading online and it looks like having two sites
running on the same instance is not possible using Elastic Beanstalk?

We are currently running under the free tier and are trying to squeeze every penny 
we can. Having to throw up another instance to host our pre-production environment 
will halve the time we have allocated for free tier usage.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly you want to do from your question. Elastic Beanstalk makes it very easy for you to roll back and forth between versions of your application. You can also easily terminate and recreate environments fairly quickly. If you don't need your "production" destination 100% of the time, couldn't you just shut it down when you're not using it?